# Compare if a date in a select is in the future

Tags: jquery

I have the following values in a dropdown, there are many times but only the first value shown here:

```
<select id="wpforms-74405-field_36"><option value="3/24/2020 - 1:15 PM" >3/24/2020 - 1:15 PM</option>....
```

I want to ".remove" any options that have passed. Hiding options with JS is not the ideal solution, I know. I can't seem to get new Date() to accept 3/24/2020 - 1:15 PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Moment.js as Daniel suggested. Parsing "MM/DD/YYYY" into a Date object.

```
var currentlyd = new Date();
$('#wpforms-74405-field_36 > option').each(function() {
var meow = $(this).val();
var currentlyd = moment(currentlyd).add(1, 'hours');
var bigmeow = new Date(moment(meow, "MM/DD/YYYY - hh:mm A"));
var bool = (moment(bigmeow).isAfter(moment(currentlyd)));
if (bool == false && isNaN(bigmeow) == false) {
$(this).remove();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as moment.js for more advanced parsing, but there is probably a simpler solution assuming you can modify the contents of your dropdown.

I would add a data attribute to each `<option>` (or change the value, if you're not using it for anything else) to hold the respective date's time value (ms since epoch).  Such as:

```
<option value="3/24/2020 - 1:15 PM" data-time="1585090680723">3/24/2020 - 1:15 PM</option>
```

I don't know how you're generating your option list, but most any language is going to let you retrieve the numeric time value from a date.

Then you can easily compare that value to `new Date().getTime()` to see if it is less than now.

Comment: Daniel, I think you're right, adding a data attribute would be a good solution. In this case, I can't.

Comment: If you can't add anything or modify your format, moment.js is probably worth a look then.  It's fairly lightweight and easy to work with.

Comment: Moment was the key!